# jQuery .load() post issue

Tags: jquery, post, load

This code is working perfectly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function(){
    $("#output").load("extract.php", {query: $("#input").val()} );
  });
});
```

However, when I change the link from extract.php to the same exact file on an external server, the script stops working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function(){
    $("#output").load("http://example.com/extract.php", {query: $("#input").val()} );
  });
});
```

According to firebug, the latter script is posting to the external file, but there is no response for some reason. Any thoughts? Greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You cannot sent POST requests to an external server, it's called the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: ajax same origin policy - duplicate of a million other questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote @Rocket:

> You cannot sent POST requests to an external server, it's called the [Same Origin Policy.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

What you can, however, do, is use some server-side code (such as PHP) hosted locally to make that POST request for you. Here is one such post describing one way to do it: [jQuery AJAX Proxy (with POST data) in PHP](http://www.coderkid.co.cc/2010/02/06/jquery-ajax-proxy-post-data-php/)